# Request time out error when getting access token using MSAL library "confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient"

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, windows-services, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to run a console application as a windows service which communicates with outlook exchange online using EWS. This has OAuth authentication and for that AppID is registered on the Azure portal. I am able to generate access token and communicate with exchange online successfully.
However when run from a remote server, it gives request timeout error. Request to the endpoint to get access token is timing out.

Can you please help me with this. I'm not able to identify the issue.
Below the access code:

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["tenantId"])
                .Build();
var ewsScopes = new string[] { ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EWSScope"] };  
var accessTokenRequest = cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes);
var accessToken = accessTokenRequest.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken;
```

Below error

`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Request to the endpoint timed out. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.<ExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.<ExecuteWithRetryAsync>d__12.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<HandleTokenRefreshErrorAsync>d__27.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__12.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

Answer (score 0):

Does the remote server have access to the authentication endpoint eg login.microsoftonline.com. Is there any proxying being used ? you could try running the ewseditor from that remote server https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases to see if you can authenticate using oAuth